# Were balloons banned by the Taliban?

Tags: afghanistan, taliban

I came across the following annotation to Simon Norfolk's "Former Teahouse in a Park, Kabul":

> Banned by the Taliban, balloons have emerged as one of the symbols of
>   freedom from authoritarian rule that Afghans celebrate. (Val Williams, "[When Photography Really Works](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764147897)", 2012)

Were balloons really banned by the Taliban? I could not find any reference supporting this claim.

[image]([source](http://easternartreport.net/afghanistan-chronotopia-by-simon-norfolk/))

Comment: I’ve encountered many sources saying that *kites* were banned.

Comment: The ban on kites followed the following "logic". Kites were used for kite battles, people would bet on the battles and gambling is haram; so kite flying is also haram.  Of course, the Taliban never needed "logic" to ban something.

Comment: @JamesK without wanting to defend the talibans at all, it seems that in some countries the approach to kites is rather extreme (at least by Western standards): `Kite flying is currently banned in some regions of Pakistan as some kite fliers engage in kite battles by coating their strings with glass or shards of metal, leading to injuries and death.`  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighter_kite#Pakistan. Also a news piece about an incident killing two children and a man in India http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-37115032.

Comment: This is a question which does not ask about how and why laws are made, but rather a question about what the law is/was in a particular place. That makes this question off-topic on Politics Stack Exchange. But it might be on-topic on https://law.stackexchange.com or, considering that you are dealing with a dubious claim made by someone else, on https://skeptics.stackexchange.com. Please consider reposting on either site after you read their respective on-topic policies and guidelines.